# Venn diagramm: at least one not

Tags: statistics, elementary-set-theory

I have trouble understanding the solution for a venn-diagram exercise our statistics professor gave us. 
The question is:

> Of the three events $A, B, C\subset W$ occurs **at least one not**. 
> Write the
>   corresponding event and draw the venn diagram.

The correct solution was:

$(\overline {A\text{ }\cup B\text{ } \cup C}\text{ })$

[image]

My solution was:

$(\overline{A\text{ }\cap B\text{ }\cap\text{ }C}\text{ })$

[image]

I just can't wrap my head around where I went wrong. If only A, or A and B happens for example, the requirement of one not is still met, isn't it? So the overlap of one or only one should be colored in too. That's at least my thought

Comment: "At least one" means *either* $A$, or $B$, or $C$, or $A$ and $B$, or $A$ and $C$, or $B$ and $C$, or $A$, $B$, and $C$. That is, **any** of the three. Negating that means not $A$, and not $B$, and not $C$ (that is, **none**). Your picture negates *all* of them. For example, in your picture, you allow for something in $A$ but not $B$ and not $C$; that something is in "at least one", so it should be excluded.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I would read the question as "there is at least one event that does not occur", instead of "it is not the case that there occurs at least one". This would make the solution of Aaron the correct one.

Comment: @Vsotvep: "occurs at least one", then a negation. Of course, the grammar is lousy and language is not associative, but reading it as an attempt at reverse polish notation in language, the "not" applies to "occurs at least one", not to just "one".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, despite Borat and Waynes' World, English does not usually use *not* at the end to negative the whole sentence

Comment: @Henry: English does not generally use "not" at the end when saying mathematics, period. Like I said, "grammar is lousy".

Comment: @amWhy: Your edit removed the very formulation that this whole thing is about. I was quite confused until I looked into the edit history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the formulation "occurs at least one not" could possibly be said to be ambiguous.

Under a very strange reading of the assignment, one could interpret the phrase "at least one not" as "it is not the case that at least one of the events occurs", $\overline{A \cup B \cup C}$, which is equivalent to "none of the events occurs", $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B} \cap \overline{C}$, and thus corresponds to the Venn diagram suggested in the solution.

However, the more straightforward (and in my judgement, the only acceptable from a grammatical point of view) reading is that "for at least one of the events it holds that it does not occur", $\overline{A} \cup \overline{B} \cup \overline{C}$, equivalently "it is not the case that all of the events occur", $\overline{A \cap B \cap C}$, which corresponds to the situation you correctly pictured in your Venn diagram.

I find it very hard to see that the first reading would be the expected interpretation or even possible at all, and think that your professor should have accepted your solution.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too... But I wasn't sure if my thinking had some sort if flaw in it. Thanks for clarifying!